# how do i add a computer to a remote domain when AD is not visable?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, vpn

What is the best way to connect a client to a domain where the network is not visable to the client? 
The network i wish to connect the client to is a virtual network on a server, the client is a physical machine located on the companies subnet. i have an server that is has a connection to both networks and is part of the virtual networks domain.

I am having trouble connecting the client machine to the domain, do i need any additional services running on the edge server allowing me to connect the client to the domain?

Edit:
sorry forgot to mention
Client : XP sp3

DC: windows 2003 R2 x64

Comment: is the server connected to both network a DC ? XP machine will need to get dns resolution on the target ad domain and access to a DC. It musn't be more than 5 minutes behind/ahead in time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't.  Your XP client must be able to contact the domain in order to join it.  You'll need to work on getting communication set up between the domain and client.

First, make sure the virtual network isn't set to be local-only to the VMs on that server - it's possible that this virtual network isn't "physically" accessible to the network at large.

If that's not the case, there are probably a dozen ways to make it work, but most simply, you should be able to ROUTE ADD your way to that domain.

Answer (score 1):

If it's Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2, you can use offline join to the domain
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392267%28WS.10%29.aspx

I forgot to add that you can switch kerberos from udp to tcp, useful when you have VPN or lower MTU on the path. Vista and + are using tcp by default. You can switch through a registry entry + reboot on the xp machine following this KB:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244474